# Is there a simple way to explain the parameter estimation process of MA or ARMA?

Tags: time-series, estimation, arima, optimization, moving-average

I know the ordinary least squares and gradient decent methods that are used to estimate the parameters (weights) in linear regression. But I am not that good at math and I can't understand the optimization process (the algorithm) or the parameter estimation of MA or ARMA.

Answer (score 2):

You come up with the likelihood function $LL(\theta|X)$ which is a function of the set of parameters $\theta$ given the data set $X$. You find the set of parameters $\theta$ that maximizes the function for any given sample $X$. That's simple conceptually. There is no simple way to explain how you come up with the likelihood function.

Here's an example of the simplest MA(1) process, follow the link [here](http://econ.nsysu.edu.tw/ezfiles/124/1124/img/Chapter17_MaximumLikelihoodEstimation.pdf).
Eq.12 is the model:

$$Y_t=\mu+\varepsilon_t+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}$$

The likelihood function is based on the assumption that $\varepsilon_t$ is from Gaussian distribution, AND that the sample is random. So, you could re-write this as 
$$\varepsilon_t=Y_t-(\mu+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1})$$

So, if you plug some arbitrary parameters $\hat\mu,\hat\theta$ and assume $\varepsilon_0=0$ you can estimate the errors recursively as shown on p.15:
$$\hat\varepsilon_1=Y_1-\hat\mu$$
$$\hat\varepsilon_2=Y_2-(\hat\mu+\hat\theta\hat\varepsilon_1)$$

If you forget about likelihoods for a moment, you could try to minimize the sum of squares $\sum_t e_t^2(\hat\mu,\hat\theta)$ as a function of its parameters given the dataset $Y_t$. From optimization point of view it's the same problem as maximizing some other nonlinear function $LL$, but otherwise the least squares here is not necessarily a good idea.

The actual likelihood function is in Eq.14, and you can see that it's not that different from least squares in some way. It has *negative* of sum of squares and some other terms.

Comment: the problem is that the hardest part is the optimization algorithm. i mean the way it finds the set of parameters.

Comment: the optimization is hardest in technical sense, from stats point of view it's the trivial technicality

Comment: to be honest my motivation to ask this question is that i don't know how they get the values of $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ and $\varepsilon_{t-2}$ to use in parameter estimation. I know in gradient decent they have $x$ and $y$ and they use x and y for estimation but in MA(or part of ARMA) there is no $x$(which is the error terms).

Comment: @floyd sections 4 and 5 of the course Aksakal linked to covers the MA case. Section 6 case covers the ARMA case.

Comment: @Aksakal can you provide links to other chapters in that course? I tried backtracking the http link but got 404'd.

Comment: @Alex, I don;t have the links, just found this text by web search

Comment: @Aksakal I read the MA part multiple times. please tell me if my understanding is right or wrong.  
1- we initialize $\hat\mu,\hat\theta$ with arbitrary numbers.  
2- plug them in the equations of $\hat\varepsilon_1,\hat\varepsilon_2...etc$.    
3- calculate the SSE $\sum_t e_t^2(\hat\mu,\hat\theta)$.    
If my understanding is right then How do we move from there? How do we choose the next $\hat\mu,\hat\theta$?